# How to prevent running qmake on make clean?

Tags: qt, makefile, qmake

The problems is that if pro-file was changed 'qmake' trying to generate new makefile during 'make clean'.

Steps to reproduce this situation:

1. qmake test.pro
2. touch test.pro && make clean

Here's an minimal example of pro:

```
TARGET = qmake-runs-on-make-clean  
TEMPLATE = app

warning(qmake runs even if it's make clean)
```

I want to get rid of this behaviour or at least make qmake do not proceed some parts of pro-file on 'make clean'

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research i came out with a not good looking but working solution. 
qmake has an [undocumented option](https://wiki.qt.io/Undocumented_QMake) named 'no_autoqmake'. So i passed it to CONFIG and then wrote my own Makefile target.

```
CONFIG += no_autoqmake
for(arg, QMAKE_ARGS){
    tmp = $$section(arg, =, 0, 0)
    !equals(tmp, MAKE_ARGS){
        QMAKE_ARGUMENTS += $$arg
    }
}

promod.name      = on_pro_modified
promod.target    = Makefile
promod.commands  = $$QMAKE_QMAKE $$_PRO_FILE_ $$QMAKE_ARGUMENTS MAKE_ARGS='$(MAKECMDGOALS)'
promod.depends   = $$_PRO_FILE_ $$QMAKE_INTERNAL_INCLUDED_FILES

PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$_PRO_FILE_
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += promod

contains(MAKE_ARGS, clean) : CLEAN_MODE_ACTIVATED=1
```

If someonen find out a better solution, please share.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the generated Makefile and remove the part where qmake is invoked.

But the rule is there for a reason. Maybe you are trying to solve a different problem?

Comment: Thanks for the response!
In profile i wrote some rules to check if there are all pkg-config dependencies with correct versions. For example: i need soomelib version 1.1. If there is on somelib version 1.0, qmake will exit with error.
But when i run 'make clean' this rules exute too...
I don't to modify Makefile manually. If there is any possibility to disable some check in profile on make clean, i would be very happy

Comment: so I think it is better to fix the rules you wrote